# When loading the main menu scene in Unity, I need the player position to reset even if there's a playerprefs save

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, virtual-reality, scene-manager

I need to reset the player's position in the main menu scene to 0,0,0, whether or not they have saved their playerprefs.

This is the code I'm using in Unity to reset the player's position when they exit to the Main Menu scene. This is a VR game. It works for players who haven't saved, but doesn't reset the position of players who have saved their playerprefs, and I don't know how to make that happen.

My reset position script:

```
//reset position of player in main menu scene
[SerializeField] Transform playerSpawnPosition;
[SerializeField] GameObject player;
[SerializeField] private Camera playerHead;
public void ResetPosition()
{
   var rotationAngleY = playerHead.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y 
                        - playerSpawnPosition.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
       
   player.transform.Rotate(0, -rotationAngleY, 0);
    
   var distanceDifference = playerSpawnPosition.transform.position 
                            - playerHead.transform.position;
       
   player.transform.position += distanceDifference;
}

   public void ExitToMainMenu(){
      
      if(pauseMenu == null){
         return;
      }
      pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
      if (LeftHand && RightHand)
      {
         Time.timeScale = 1f;
         LeftHand.transform.parent = leftparent;
         RightHand.transform.parent = rightParent;
      }
      
      SceneManager.LoadScene(0,LoadSceneMode.Single);
      
      ResetPosition();
      
   }
```

My Save Player Position script:

```
public void SavePlayerPosition(){
   hpc = FindObjectOfType<HVRPlayerController>();
   if(hpc == null){
      return;
   }
   PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PlayerXPos",hpc.transform.position.x);
   PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PlayerYPos",hpc.transform.position.y);
   PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PlayerZPos",hpc.transform.position.z);
   Vector3 v = hpc.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
   PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PlayerYRot",v.y);
   
   PlayerPrefs.SetString("SpawnId", "xyzSave");
   Debug.Log("Saved player to position " + hpc.transform.position.x + " "
      + hpc.transform.position.y + " "+ hpc.transform.position.z + " ");
}
public void LoadPlayerPosition(){
   hpc = FindObjectOfType<HVRPlayerController>();
   if(hpc == null){
      return;
   }
   playerX = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PlayerXPos");
   playerY = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PlayerYPos");
   playerZ = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PlayerZPos");
   playerYRot = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PlayerYRot",hpc.transform.rotation.y);
   Debug.Log("Loaded player position " + playerX + " "
      + playerY + " "+ playerZ);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely calling `LoadPlayerPosition()` after every position reset. If it's called in a Start() method in a monobehaviour, it's likely going to get called after `ResetPosition()`.

If this is the case, the 0,0,0 values for your players position might not even be set by `ResetPosition`, instead they're set to the default values returned by `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat()`, '0.0'.

### To Test

Put breakpoints on `ResetPosition();` and `hpc = FindObjectOfType<HVRPlayerController>();`. In the case where a player has set player prefs, I have a feeling your will observe that `ResetPosition();` is called before `hpc = FindObjectOfType<HVRPlayerController>();`.

### To Fix

This is a bit tricky. The solution I'd play around with is tying the two functions together in another function call. The function would have a parameter `isMainMenuReset`. If it's true, call `ResetPosition()`, else, call `LoadPlayerPosition()`. You'd have to replace all `LoadPlayerPosition()` calls in your codebase with this new function call.